# Delete belongsTo association not working

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, belongs-to, cascading-deletes

I have a problem with associations. I have two tables : Companies and Users.

```
User hasOne Company and Company belongsTo User (OneToOne)
```

In my models, I wrote :

```
/* User.php Model */
public $hasOne = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);

/* Company.php Model */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

**My problem** : when I do

```
$this->Company->delete($id, true)
```

in my CompaniesController, the Company with the id $id is deleted but the User associated is not.

Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure your data model represents User hasOne Company _(hasOne is not as common as the other associations)_? Does your user table have a company_id column? If so, then User belongsTo Company and Company hasMany User.

Comment: My User "is" a Company. But I needed to have an admin User without company. That's why I decided to have two separeted tables, not to leave null fields in my User table in the admin row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'dependent' option in `belongsTo`, so the only one actually working is the other way around.

If you delete a User, it will delete it's Company.

Basically, deleting a parent can delete it's dependent children.  But deleting a child can't delete it's "dependent" parent (since there's really no such thing in Cake's case of a "dependent parent").

More details here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

---

You could choose to run the association in both directions (requiring a field in each table to determine which it belongs to).  That way, regardless of which you delete, it should always also delete the other.

**Or, you could just delete the User that owns the company.**

Comment: I decided to delete a User instead of a Company. Thank you for your answer that was really helpful.